# Facebook App authentication w/ PHP SDK problems after temporarily changing App URL

Tags: php, facebook, oauth, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-oauth

App is having problems with authentication with a few users and I believe it stems from this:

I had temporarily changed the URL for the app to point to a different and invalid directory on the server and users who logged in during this period were stuck in an infinite redirect loop with an invalid access token (see the error below).  However, I then changed the URL back to point to the original working URL (which had been working fine) and authentication works fine for everyone, except I think for those users who had logged in during the temporary URL change, whom are still getting the infinite redirect loop error.

> "OAuthException: Error validating access token: This may be because
>   the user logged out or may be due to a system error"

Update: One of the users who was having the issue was able to be authenticated for a short period of time earlier today but now is back to the same problem.  Very strange.

Comment: Sorry, what exactly is infinitely looping? Can you describe the programmatic flow of the loop?

Comment: Perhaps this user has reverted your app permissions.

Comment: An infinite redirect loop that keeps checking for the token but throwing the error.  The main problem is that there is something wrong with the token for this user.  The user has not reverted app permissions.

Comment: Check if your app is in sandbox mode. If so - ensure the user is added to admins/developers/testers. Without this Facebook will always think user is logged out as nobody except explicitly added users has access to sandbox app.

Comment: Could your user have https only turned on in their user settings?

Comment: https works fine for other users

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing the same issue with an app and its main developer account. I've never seen this error but now it randomly shows up with `OAuthException: Error validating access token: This may be because the user logged out or may be due to a system error`.

Without changing a single line of code, now the error is gone.

This is definitely a Facebook bug. I will report this on [Facebook bugs tracker](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/) as soon I can.

**EDIT:** [here's the reported bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/179301482177807)